# Shift key is not working after Meta key (Mac OSX)

Tags: key-bindings, osx

My <kbd>Shift</kbd> key is usually working but the combination `M-S-` is not, and `M-S-` is sometimes pretty useful in `org-mode`. It's not just for `org-mode`, though. I tried `describe-key` but when I enter `S-` after `M-` nothing happens.

> For example, <kbd>M</kbd>-<kbd>></kbd> (meta+shift+period) no longer activates `end-of-buffer`.

I'm using Emacs 24.5 and I'm under OSX El capitan

Comment: what did Emacs say, when using this key stroke?

Comment: Are you using emacs in the terminal or the emacs gui? If it's in the terminal, the terminal will not send all keys to emacs.

Comment: Try `C-h k` (which is `describe-key`) before the binding.  Note that `M-S` is a modifier, so you will have to type some other character too.

Comment: Are you trying to bind a `M-S-<lower-case-letter>` sequence? If so, this would be a duplicate of [Why the key binding M-S-t fails while C-S-t works?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38180797/324105)

Comment: Emacs doesn't receive a key stroke.

Comment: However, I tested in Karabiner Event Viewer and alt_right + shift works there.  So this does seem to be an Emacs specific problem.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the keypress was being captured by [Amethyst](https://github.com/ianyh/Amethyst), a 3rd party window manager that runs inside of MacOS.  I changed the configuration of Amethyst and the keypress went through to Emacs.

Comment: I have no idea how you found that, but props to you kind sir!

Answer (score 0):

I looked into the `org-mode` source code and find the following line:

```
(org-defkey org-mode-map [(meta shift right)]  'org-shiftmetaright)
```

By looking at the other functions, I found out the use something like this:

```
(global-set-key [(meta shift right)] 'foo)
```

I tried it in my Emacs and it seems to work this way.

Answer (score 0):

When it receives an event with the shift modifier and it can't find any corresponding binding in the keymaps, Emacs then tries a second lookup in the keymaps with the shift modifier removed.

So maybe that's simply what you're seeing.